# Dar formato ITALIC a texto

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy creando una aplicacion en java swing, pero no encuentro la manera de agregar Italic al texto.

Les dejo la linea de código.

```
SumaHaberes.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Courier", 1, 12));
```

e intentado con lo siguiente pero no resulta.

```
SumaHaberes.setFont(new java.awt.Font.ITALIC("Courier", 1, 12));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los parámetros del constructor de clase **Font** son:

1. (String) Nombre de fuente o letra.
2. (int) Estilo, por ej. 0 o Font.PLAIN, 1 o Font.BOLD (negrita), 2 o Font.ITALIC (cursiva).
   Se recomienda usar las constantes de clase ya que son mas ilustrativas.
3. (int) Tamaño de fuente, por ej 12

```
//se recomienda comenzar nombre de variables con minúscula
sumaHaberes.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Italic", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: Por nada. Usa la constante Font.ITALIC

Comment: @Daxtrox Había un error. Ya edité